# How to understand complex rotation?

Tags: complex-numbers, rotations

I come across [A Visual, Intuitive Guide to Imaginary Numbers](https://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-intuitive-guide-to-imaginary-numbers/), and find it's difficult for me to understand this [section](https://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-intuitive-guide-to-imaginary-numbers/#A_Real_Example_Rotations):

> Let’s take a look. Suppose I’m on a boat, with a heading of 3 units East for every 4 units North. I want to change my heading 45 degrees counter-clockwise. What’s the new heading?
> ......
> Let’s try a simpler approach: we’re on a heading of 3 + 4i (whatever that angle is; we don’t really care), and want to rotate by 45 degrees. Well, 45 degrees is 1 + i (perfect diagonal), so we can multiply by that amount!
> [image]

Per my understanding, rotation should not change the distance from `0`, but it's obviously the distance of `3 +　4i` isn't same with `-1 + 7j`. How to understand complex rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are only interested in the angle. If you want to preserve the magnitude, you must multiply by a complex number of absolute value one; in this example, you should take $(1+i)/\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you to familiarize with a **polar form** of a complex number (see [at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form)), defined by an [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula):

$$m(\cos \varphi + i\sin\varphi) = m\,e^{i\varphi}$$

where $m$ is a magnitude of the complex number (i.e. the corresponding vector's length) and $\varphi$ is its argument (i.e. the angle from the real axis).

Then, applying standard laws of multiplication of products and powers:

$$z_1 \cdot z_2 = |z_1|e^{i\varphi_1} \cdot |z_2|e^{i\varphi_2} = |z_1|\,|z_2|\cdot e^{i(\varphi_1 + \varphi_2)}$$

a product of two numbers has a magnitude being a product of magnitudes of the two terms, and an argument being a sum of their arguments.

Your number $(1+i)$ has a magnitude $\sqrt{1^2+1^2} = \sqrt 2$ and argument $\arctan \frac 11 = 45^\circ$, hence in multiplication of $(3+4i)$ by $(1+i)$ the vector representing a product is longer than that of $(3+4i)$ by a factor of $\sqrt 2$ and rotated by $45^\circ$.